# MVC 4 Bootstrap Modal Edit \ Detail

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

Hoping someone might be able to help me with something I am experimenting with in MVC 4 using bootstrap.

I have a strongly-typed index view which displays items in a table along with edit and delete action icons in each line.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.EquipmentClass>

....

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.ClassId
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ClassName
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href=@Url.Action("Edit", "EquipmentClass", new { id = item.ClassId })>
                <i class="icon-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a href=@Url.Action("Delete", "EquipmentClass", new { id = item.ClassId })>
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
} <!-- foreach -->
```

The EquipmentClass controller returns the Edit view for the selected item based on the id.  All great and as expected at this point

```
public ViewResult Edit(int id)
{
    return View(equipmentclassRepository.Find(id));
}
```

What I would like to know is how to open the edit form in a bootstrap modal dialog.

I could try and substitute the edit action in the table with the following and then have a modal div at the bottom of the view but how do I pass in the ID of the selected item and which html helper should I use in the modal section?

```
<!-- replaced table action -->
<a class="btn pull-right" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Details</a>

....

<!-- modal div -->
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="myModal" )>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        @Html.Partial("Edit")
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any advice, many thanks

Answer (score 13):

I think that I have a solution to your problem. To make your MVC application work as you want it to you should make some changes to the code you provided:

**1.** Add a *div* representing a modal for editing an item at the bottom of your layout page:

```
<div id="editModalContainerID" class="modal hide fade" data-url='@Url.Action("Edit", "EquipmentClass")'> 
<div id="editModalBodyID"></div> 
</div>
```

Notice that this modal is strictly connected to the controller action responsible for editing an *EquipmentClass* item.

**2.** Add a *jQuery* function to your custom javaScript:

```
function showModal(modalContainerId, modalBodyId, id) {
    var url = $(modalContainerId).data('url');

    $.get(url, { id: id }, function (data) {
        $(modalBodyId).html(data);
        $(modalContainerId).modal('show');
    });
}
```

As you can see this function takes *id* as one of its parameters. In general its purpose is to replace the empty modal body with what we will put in a separate partial view and than display whole container as a modal page.

**3.** Put your modal div in a separate partial view, and call it *Edit* (has to be the same as your controller action name). You will have to change your *Edit* partial name to sth else, for example *EditBody*.

The *Edit* partial view should now look sth like this:

```
@model EquipmentClass

<!-- modal div -->
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @Html.Partial("EditBody", Model)
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
</div>
```

**4.** Change the controller action so that it returns the partial view created in the previous step:

```
public PartialViewResult Edit(int id)
{
    return PartialView(equipmentclassRepository.Find(id));
}
```

**5.** Change the *edit* 'a' anchor so that it calls created *jQuery* function:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.EquipmentClass>

....

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.ClassId
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ClassName
        </td>
        <td>
            <a data-toggle="modal" onclick="showModal('#editModalContainerID', '#editModalBodyID', @item.ClassId)">
                <i class="icon-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a href=@Url.Action("Delete", "EquipmentClass", new { id = item.ClassId })>
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
} <!-- foreach -->
```

This way each time an 'a' anchor with edit icon is clicked the showModal function (with related id being passed) is fired and a bootstrap modal with related data is displayed.

I'm sure there is a better way to do it, but this way worked for me just fine :)

Hope this helps you a bit :)

Answer (score 3):

Przemo answer worked for me, however do note that I only managed to get it to work when I changed the first block of code from

```
<div id="editModalContainerID" class="modal hide fade" data-url='@Url.Action("Edit", "EquipmentClass")'> 
<div id="editModalBodyID"></div> 
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="editModalContainerID" class="modal fade" data-url='@Url.Action("Edit", "EquipmentClass")'> 
<div id="editModalBodyID"></div> 
</div>
```

Notice that I removed the "fade" class from editModalContainerID. Otherwise the partial view does not load. Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: You've actually removed the `hide` class from your answer, not `fade`.