# Binding the MVC Form Helper to a Bootstrap modal

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

Working with a series of MVC-driven forms where I would like to leverage the conventional `'@using (Html.BeginForm(...'` method of generating client-side forms that will be rendered inside Bootstrap-based modals. [I've found a technique that binds the modal](https://gist.github.com/havvg/3226804) to an ajax request/response scheme where the form is defined thusly:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal well" data-async data-target="#rating-modal" action="/some-endpoint" method="POST">
```

I understand how to insert the class attributes ( `new { @class="example"}` )  but I haven't found samples that show me how to deal with the 'data-async' and 'data-target=xxx'.

Wondering if Darin Dimitrov's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970184/accessing-attributes-from-custom-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-4-razor?rq=1) is partial answer to my need. Or perhaps I need to better understand EditorTemplates [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699068/mvc-4-bootstrap-modal-edit-detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you do with a class:

```
new { @class="example"}
```

For a data-atribute can do:

```
new { @class="example", data_target="#rating-modal"}
```

`data_target` output `data-target` when razor interpret the htmlAttributes parameter

Comment: Thanks much - but what about 'data-async' that has no right hand value? I've tried '..., new {data_async, data_target="#rating-modal"} // errors The name 'data_async' does not exist in the current context and new {data_async=null, data_target="#rating-modal"} and get similar erro. Trying new {data_async="", data_target="#rating-modal"} will render data-async="" but i be surprised if that didn't come with it's own set of problems. --appreciated

Comment: I think `new {data_async="true", data_target="#rating-modal"}` should do the work. http://jsfiddle.net/9mQdH/. the JS is just asking for an attribute of name `data-async` no matter the value.